# Interact with QProcess - reading and writing to QProcess results in no output

Tags: c++, qt, stdin, cin, qprocess

*noted: this is a use-specific question, but I hope others can benefit from this too*

**To get a basic sense of what I want to do:**

QProcess runs a command by:

```
QProcess::start("sh -c \"cd /tmp/tempdir ; ./my_script --option file.txt ; echo $?\" ")
```

The script expects input from the user (a password), `QProcess::readAll()` confirms the script's input request. The input is given by `QProcess::write()`.

**Here I get lost!** -> No output is received. from `readAll()` and `readAllStandardOutput()`,  both are empty.

**I need the output:** particularly the `echo $?` for later processing, but don't get anything since `readAll()` and `readAllStandardOutput()` returns empty strings

To me there are several possible issues to cause this, maybe more than one:

- The script does not receive this input
- The script receives the input, but expects a "return key press"
- The script receives the input, QProcess::write automatically does a "return key press", the script continues and finishes but QProcess does not read this output

**The Code:**

// please ignore the messiness of the code, a placed a number of debugs just to see the code response.

> cmd = "cd /tmp/tempdir ; ./my_script --option file.txt ; echo $?"      (without quotes)
>
> input => required input for script

```
QString gen_serv::runCommand(QString cmd, QString input){
    Process *p = new QProcess(parent);
    p->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    //    p->start("sh ", QStringList() << " -c " << cmd);
    QString c = QString("sh -c \"" + cmd + "\" ");
    p->start(c);                                                <---- ACTUAL COMMAND : sh -c "cd /tmp/tempdir ; ./my_script --option file.txt ; echo $?"
    if (p->waitForStarted()) {
        if (!p->waitForReadyRead()) {
            qDebug(log_lib_gen_serv) << "waitForReadyRead() [false] : CODE: " << QVariant(p->error()).toString() << " | ERROR STRING: " << p->errorString();
        }
        if (!p->waitForFinished(1000)) {
            qDebug() << p->readAll();
            qDebug() << p->readAllStandardOutput();
            //p->write(input.toLatin1());
            p->write(QString(input + QString("\n")).toLatin1());           <--- added this "\n" incase the process/console was waiting for a return press, thus the /n should satisfy the return requirement
            qDebug() << p->readAll();
            qDebug() << p->readAllStandardOutput();
            if (!p->waitForFinished()) {
                qDebug() << p->readAll();
                qDebug() << p->readAllStandardOutput();
                qDebug(log_lib_gen_serv) << "waitForFinished() [false] : CODE: " << QVariant(p->error()).toString() << " | ERROR STRING: " << p->errorString();
            }
            qDebug() << p->readAll();
            qDebug() << p->readAllStandardOutput();
        }
        QString s = QString(p->readAll() + p->readAllStandardOutput());
        return s;
    }
    else{
        qDebug(log_lib_gen_serv) << "waitForStarted() [false] : CODE: " << QVariant(p->error()).toString() << " | ERROR STRING: " << p->errorString();
    }
    p->waitForFinished();
    p->kill();
    return QString();
}
```

**Please note:**

The script is long and complicated, however it returns a message "done" if successfully executed and an exit code for each case.

Thus the `echo $?` should capture and return this for processing i.e. `return s`

I hope this makes sense, any suggestions how I can attempt to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848939/reading-and-writing-to-qprocess-in-qt-console-application)?

Comment: @Tarod keen eye, yes, this one is where I was in the early stages of "the struggle" :p I will be closing this question as it is pointless. And not to lay it on anymore, but I really appreciate the help. I know it has saved me atleast a day of struggling! Thank you!

Comment: You are a kind person :) Thanks to you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading and writing to QProcess in Qt Console Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848939/reading-and-writing-to-qprocess-in-qt-console-application)

Comment: For reference, don’t use `$?` like this: you get better and easier information from [QProcess::exitCode()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitCode) (and `exitStatus`).